# What is the best way to consult the source code of a Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, argparse

Well, I'm working with `argparse` Python package and would like to check its implementation in way of figure out some architecture points.

I have `Python 3.6.9` installed in my machine and I supposed would be possible to check it locally, is there a way?

Anyway, any alternative is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check locally, it'll be in your Python installation, at a path like `/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py`. Alternatively, you can look at it online: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.9/Lib/argparse.py

Answer (score 3):

Pure python modules include a reference to their location on disk. Just

```
import argparse
print(argparse.__file__)
```